# python hug - Cannot use Nested in MarshmallowSchema

Tags: python, marshmallow, hug

Using HUG for building a Rest API, VERSION 2.3.0 (https://github.com/timothycrosley/hug)

I cannot use the Nested ability of Marshmallow in HUG. Here is some code.

```
import config
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
import hug
import hashlib
import logging
import os
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validates, ValidationError

class MultilanguageSchema(Schema):
    language = fields.Str()
    value = fields.Str()

class TitleSchema(Schema):
    titles = fields.Nested(MultilanguageSchema, many = True)

class DescriptionSchema(Schema):
    descriptions = fields.Nested(MultilanguageSchema, many = True)

@hug.post('/ads', requires=api_key_authentication, versions=1)
def post_ad(sites_id: hug.types.number,
        name: hug.types.text,
        age: hug.types.in_range(18, 99),
        telephone: hug.types.number,

        titles: hug.types.MarshmallowSchema(TitleSchema()),
        descriptions: hug.types.MarshmallowSchema(DescriptionSchema()),

        authed_user: hug.directives.user):

    pdb.set_trace()
```

When I try to do a POST request with this example data I got empty data on the Nested fields.

```
sites_id: 1
name: Test Name
age: 34
telephone: 999999999
titles: {"language":"en","value":"Some Title"}
descriptions: {"language":"en","value":"Some Description"}
```

Using pdb:

```
titles: {}
descriptions: {}
```

Anyone have been able to use the Nested ability of Marshmallow in HUG. If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to define your endpoint like this, and access the data based on the new signature?

```
@hug.post('/ads')
def post_ad(*args, **kwargs):
    print('Args: %s' % args)
    print('Kwargs: %s' % kwargs)
    try:
        sites_id = kwargs.get('sites_id', None)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This [issue](https://github.com/timothycrosley/hug/issues/120) raised here might be of interest.